# Xamarin Forms - Binding Listview for lazy loading

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, xamarin.forms, listviewitem

Started to dabble in Xamarin Forms.
Two things I cant figure out:

Binding of my Listview:

I have a class with:

```
    public class Mainlist
    {
        public string Title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Value
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
```

My XAML looks like:

```
   <ListView x:Name="mainlist">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Font="18"></Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Value}" TextColor="Gray"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

What happens now is that i have a list of URLS. From every URL I am scraping certain info with HTMLAgilityPack foreach loop, which is working fine.

I would like to add the scraped data after each run of the loop to the listview and have it display. Something like "lazy loading".

Up to now i could only figure out how to set the itemsource after all Urls are scraped and have it display at once with something like this:

```
 //set itemsource to URL collection
            mainlist.ItemsSource = new List<Mainlist>() {
                new Mainlist()
            {

              //scraped info from each URL
                    Title = title.ToString().Trim(),
                    Value = value.ToString().Trim(),

                },
            };
```

Comment: Look into using MVVM pattern, it'll make solving this problem fairly simple

Comment: @sme if you could help me out would be great then. i've been trying loads.

Comment: I posted an answer below now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a view model class, called *MyViewModel.cs*:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // property changed event handler
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<Mainlist> _list;

    public ObservableCollection<Mainlist> List
    {
        get { return _list; }
        set
        {
            _list = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(List)));
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        _list = new ObservableCollection<Mainlist>();
    }

    public async void StartScraping()
    {
        // assuming you are 'awaiting' the results of your scraping method...
        foreach (...)
        {
            await ... scrape a web page ...

            var newItem = new Mainlist()
            {
                Title = title.ToString().Trim(),
                Value = value.ToString().Trim()
            };

            // if you instead have multiple items to add at this point,
            // then just create a new List<Mainlist>, add your items to it,
            // then add that list to the ObservableCollection List.

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
            {
                List.Add(newItem);
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Now in your page's `xaml.cs` code behind file, set the view model as your `BindingContext`:

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage // (assuming the page is called "MyPage" and is of type ContentPage)
{
    MyViewModel _viewModel;

    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        BindingContext = _viewModel;
        // bind the view model's List property to the list view's ItemsSource:
        mainList.setBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "List");
    }
}
```

And note that in your view model, you'll need to use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of a `List<T>`, as `ObservableCollection<T>` will allow the `ListView` to be updated automatically whenever you add or remove items from it.

Also, to ease a bit of confusion, I'd recommend changing the class name from `Mainlist` to `MainListItem`.

Comment: perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I updated the method, I just had to assume how you are going about scraping the web pages. It might be a bit more clear now

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do something like this:

```
mainlist.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Mainlist>();

foreach (var item in yourDataFromHtmlAgilityPackScraping) {
    mainlist.ItemsSource.Add(new Mainlist()
            {
                //scraped info from each URL
                Title = item.title.ToString().Trim(),
                Value = item.value.ToString().Trim(),
            });
}
```

The important part here is the ObservableCollection. Which allows the Listview to be updated when a new element is added.

Comment: Thanks, yes, something like this i'm looking for. Like this it gives me an error on the "Add" though saying : There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter. looks like some syntax issue here.