# Set records to show on listview by 10 records at at time in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin forms.

I have 200 records to show on listview, but I want to load only 10 records to show. When I scroll the listview, the next 10 records should show.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Forms - Binding Listview for lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420001/xamarin-forms-binding-listview-for-lazy-loading). Also check this blogpost: http://www.codenutz.com/lac09-xamarin-forms-infinite-scrolling-listview/

Answer (score 0):

Use custom paging using your defined next and the previous button.
use LINQ to take/skip for every 10 records. Save count with Label and set its IsVisible property to false.

```html
public List<Product> List(int page =1, string category =null)
{
    if (category != null) this.CurrentCategory = category;

    var products = repository.Products
                   .Where(p => this.CurrentCategory == null || p.Category == this.CurrentCategory)
                   .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
                   .Skip((page -1) * PageSize)
                   .Take(PageSize);

var count = repository.Products
                   .Where(p => this.CurrentCategory == null || p.Category == this.CurrentCategory).Count();

var resultAsPagedList = products.ToList();

    return resultAsPagedList;
}
```

Please let me know if you require more information.