# Xamarin Forms: How to handle big data in ListView?

Tags: forms, listview, xamarin

I need to show very big data in a ListView. Must I load all the
data once? My code is below:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Brunie.Mobile.ViewModels {
    public class VmListCompany {
        public ObservableCollection<Company> AllCompanies {
            get;
        } = new ObservableCollection<Company>();
        public VmListCompany() {
            LoadAllCompanies();
        }
        private void LoadAllCompanies() {
            Company company = null;
            while(null != (company = GetNextCompany(company))) {
                AllCompanies.Add(company);
            }
        }
        private bool HasNextCompany(Company company) {
            bool hasNextCompany = false;
            ......
            return (hasNextCompany);
        }
        private Company GetNextCompany(Company company) {
            if(!HasNextCompany(company)) {
                return (null);
            }
            Company nextCompany = new Company();
            ......
            return (nextCompany);
        }
    }
    public class Company {
        public string Name {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Address {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int NumberOfEmployees {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

> ListView in Xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllCompanies}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

> After called LoadAllCompanies the count of AllCompanies is 20562104.
>   So my app is very slow now.
>   How to handle this situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin Forms - Binding Listview for lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420001/xamarin-forms-binding-listview-for-lazy-loading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Chetan said using API pagination is the best approach .
That being said if for some reason you can't change the pagination ( let's say its a third party API) you can still improve your performance by optimizing your caching strategy of the listview
as shown in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance)

Comment: Hi @King23 but in normal user not check 20562104 record so why we need load data in ListView. I think we need to load data in List<ModelName> and use pagination in UI side

Comment: @ChetanRawat Dont misunderstand me. Your answer is the right one, pagination is the way to go, but seeing as he has a lot of records, if the user keeps scrolling trough the pagination pages optimizing the list view is recommended to further enhance user experience

Answer (score 1):

Use Pagination in API side and load data on ListItemAppearing