# Xamarin Forms: Infinite Scroll in CollectionView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uicollectionview, .net-5

I have an Api with pagination in which I have 1000 records but I want to show the first 20 and so on, on my CollectionView, I have seen an SO answer which sais that I should "Use Pagination in API side and load data on ListItemAppearing" but I don't know how to achieve this.

Here's the answer that I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60205866/18972374

Please help and thanks.

**EDIT**

I have seen that when having a listview it is possible to use Xamarin.Forms.Extended.InfiniteScrolling but it doesn't work for collectionView. Still don't know how to achieve this

**EDIT 2**

I'm trying to use this

```
RemainingItemsThreshold="4"
                            RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadMoreCommand}"
```

This is what I have but it keeps giving me this exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'
```

This is my `LoadMore` method that I call on my `LoadMoreCommand`

```
 private async void LoadMore()
        {
            if (IsBusy)
                return;

            IsBusy = true;

            // load the next page
            var page = ListCart.Count / pageSize;

            //calling api
            var carts = await GetListCart(pageSize, page);

            _oListCart.AddRange(carts);

            IsBusy = false;
        }
```

This my CollectionView

```
<CollectionView x:Name="ListViewCart" 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ListCart}" 
                            RemainingItemsThreshold="4"
                            RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadMoreCommand}"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                            SelectionMode = "Single"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding CartSelected}"                      
                            SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding ShowAlertCommand}"
                            SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding CartSelected, Source={RelativeSource Self}}"
                           >....
```

Comment: You can use the mvvm and set the first 20 items into a ObservableCollection as the data source, please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420001/xamarin-forms-binding-listview-for-lazy-loading).

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT yes but how would I keep loading items?

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this official link [Load data incrementally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#load-data-incrementally)

Comment: I have MVVM architecture and the official link doesn't help. I will upload the code that I have for know

Comment: please add your Viewmodel code @robluc

Comment: Use ObservableCollection instead of List in Binding to update in view.

Answer (score 0):

That `InvalidOperationException` happens because Xamarin was using the ObservableCollection internally (to display items while scroll), at the time `RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand` calls your command.

To fix this, slightly delay the line that adds to the collection. You do this by *queueing* it back to MainThread, to run after your command returns.
Change:

```cs
_oListCart.AddRange(carts);

IsBusy = false;
```

To:

```cs
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    try
    {
        _oListCart.AddRange(carts);
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
});
```